# Python calling function from other function and passing parameter

Tags: python, flask, redirect

To whoever downvoted my question because they saw there were related answers. The only related question/answers I saw was about redirecting to a full URL. I want to know how to redirect to another function so I can pass a parameter. PLEASE re-read my issue before jumping to conclusions.

My problem: If the user is directed to /userLogoutGo, I'd like that function to pass the message you see on to the index function and have that function open its template. Please help me see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for, session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/userLogin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(myParam=''):
    if myParam != '':
        t_message = myParam
    else:
        t_message = "Login or Register"
    return render_template("user_register.html",
                           t_message=t_message,
                           t_js="user_register.js",
                           t_title=t_message,
                           id_user=id_user)
                           
@app.route('/userLogoutGo', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userLogoutGo():
    global id_user
    id_user = 0
    a = index("Logged out. Now you can Log In or Register")
```

Comment: I think what you want to do is using the redirect function of flask.

Comment: You can safely use `"Login or Register"` as the default argument instead of `''`, since `str` values are immutable.

Comment: Seeing error whether I use Flask or flask: ```return Flask.redirect(Flask.url_for('/userLogin'))
AttributeError: type object 'Flask' has no attribute 'redirect'
``` ```
return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('/userLogin'))
NameError: name 'flask' is not defined```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is using the redirect function from flask. Then the user will be redirected to the loginurl and the index function will be run.